# Giving user the power to add SQL constraints, Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

I have a strange need, a customer asked me to implement a webapp to support his database. Since I love Django I decided to use it.

The extra need which I have difficult with is as follow: the user should have the extra "power" to create model constraints like checking the range of an IntegerField, all without knowing anything about Python.

So, I have some ideas but I'm not sure what is (if there is) the correct one. Here's my thoughts:

1. Implement a template-side validation using JavaScript
2. Implement a Python Script and a userfriendly way to use it that writes the models.py file (this sounds terrible)
3. Write some Admin Actions using a raw SQL CHECK constraint, but I still don't know how

Is this request solvable? Can you give me a tip about the simplest way to do it?

Thanks in advance,

--
Flavio

Comment: I wont recommend javascript to solve the issue. Perfomance-wise, this is a terrible idea, at least if you expect to end up with hundreds or thousands of items in a queryset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible indeed. We will use [custom object manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) and [dynamic Q objects](http://www.michelepasin.org/techblog/2010/07/20/the-power-of-djangos-q-objects/) to solve the issue. Here's an example.

1. Create an appropriate model to store info about constraints. Note that we create ForeginKey to [`ContentType`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) in order to tie our constraint to a specific model class.

   ```
   #your_app/models.py
   from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User

   class PerUserConstraint(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User)
       content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
       field_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
       predicate = models.CharField(max_length = 255) #for example, 'contains' etc.
       filter_value = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
   ```
2. Create a custom manager, register it with your models.

   ```
    #your_app/models.py
    from django.db.models.query_utils import Q

    class ConstraintedManager(models.Manager):
        def get_constrainted_query(self, user):
            qs = self.model.objects.all()
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model.__class__)
            constraints = PerUserConstraint.objects.filter(
                                                 user = user,
                                                 content_type = content_type
            )
            if constraints:
                filters = []
                for constraint in constraints:
                    filters.append(('%s__%s' % (constraint.field_name, constraint.predicate), constraint.value)
                # at this point filters should look like this:
                # [('question__contains', 'dinner'), ('question__contains', 'meal')]
                q_list = [Q(x) for x in filters]
                return qs.filter(reduce(operator.and_, q_list))
                # which is something like 
                # return qs.filter(Q(question__contains = 'dinner') & Q(question__contains = 'meal'))

           else:
               return qs     

    class YourModel(models.Model):
        #some fields
        ... 
        c = ConstraintedManager()
   ```

So in your views you will be able to use it like this: `YourModel.c.get_constrainted_query(user)`

Note that I didn't test this code, but I hope you've grasped the concept.

To override queries inside ModelAdmin, use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany) techniques.